# Replacing an element in table with indices other than i & j

Tags: pattern-matching, list-manipulation

I have a function F, of four other f functions, as shown below (1, 2, 3, 4 are indices here, while m is an integer)

```
F = f[m, 1]*f[m, 2]*f[m, 3]*f[m, 4]
```

I want to create a table using this function such that for each (i, j)th element f[m, i], f[m, j] and other f[m, k] (where k is a number other than i & j in (i,j)th element) elements are replaced by f[m-2, i], f[m-2,j] and f[m-1, k] respectively.

Replacing f[m, i] and f[m, j] is easy as follows, but I am not able to figure out how to represent the third replacement for indices other than i and j in F.

```
G = Table[F/.{f[m, i] -> f[m-2, i], f[m, j] -> f[m-2, j]}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

In my previous post, I got the suggestion to use "_" or "Except[i|j]" for k. These suggestion like

```
f[m, _] -> f[m-1, _]
```

successfully converts m to m-1 but then k is also replaced by symbols "_" or "Except[i|j]" in stead of giving a value.

For example f[m, 4] in {1, 2}th element of table gives f[m-1, _], not f[m-1, 4] as expected. I will appreciate any further help on this.
thanks

Comment: what is an acceptable range for `m`?

Comment: This table I have to use in "For" function later on where m =  2 - 6.

Answer (score 2):

When we type `f[m,k] /. f[m,_] -> f[m-1,_]` at the prompt, we get back `f[m-1,_]`, which does not seem too surprising.  The trick is to name the blank and use the name in place of the blank on the right hand side of the ->, like this:

```
f[m,k] /. f[m,x_] -> f[m-1,x]
(*  f[-1+m, k]  *)
```

However, that is still not exactly what we need, since `x` could have a value and we want the value of the blank named `x`, not the variable `x`.  So, what we really want is to use `RuleDelayed` (:>), as

```
f[m,k] /. f[m,x_] :> f[m-1,x]
(*  f[-1+m, k]  *)
```

That works even when `x` has a value.

In other words, try this:

```
F = f[m, 1]*f[m, 2]*f[m, 3]*f[m, 4];

G = Table[F /. {f[m, i] -> f[m - 2, i], f[m, j] -> f[m - 2, j],
    f[m, x_] :> f[m - 1, x]}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the `F` function as follows

```
F[m_,i_,j_]:=Module[{rls},
  rls = {
    f[arg1_, arg2_] :> f[arg1 - 2, arg2] /; MemberQ[{i, j}, arg2], 
    f[arg1_, arg2_] :> f[arg1 - 1, arg2] /; Not[MemberQ[{i, j}, arg2]]
   };

  Fold[ReplaceAll[#1, #2] &, f[m, 1] f[m, 2] f[m, 3] f[m, 4], rls]
]
```

Evaluating `F[m,1,3]` returns

```
f[-2 + m, 1] f[-2 + m, 3] f[-1 + m, 2] f[-1 + m, 4]
```

Effectively, what the solution does is to apply repeatedly the transformation rules for `f[m,i]`; it first tackles the case where `i,j`'s in the `f`'s are equal to the inputs and then deals with all the remaining cases (ie those indexes not equal to either of the inputs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single replacement rule as follows

```
G = Table[F /. f[m, k_] :> f[m - 1 - Boole[MemberQ[{i, j}, k]], k], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

Also

```
H = Table[F /. f[m, k_] :> f[m - 1 - (k /. {i | j -> 1, _ -> 0}), k], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

and

```
ClearAll[h]
h[i_, _, i_] := 2
h[_, i_, i_] := 2
h[_, _, _] := 1

M = Table[F /. f[m, k_] :> f[m - h[i, j, k], k], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];

G == H == M
```

> True